# How do you enable selection on items in a list without disabling hit testing on the list items?

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I'm trying to create a file browser where the user can drag and drop entries in my LibraryView on to the main view to display them. Also working is are context menus where the user can right click to delete or edit preferences on a file. The problem is, if I disable hit testing on the Text label of the file, I can't drag and drop the file, but selection works...if I enable hit testing I can't click on the Text label of the file to select it. Here's my code, any help would be appreciated...

```
struct LibraryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LibraryViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $viewModel.selectedNodes) {
            ForEach(viewModel.nodes, id: \.self) { node in
                if let childrenNodes = node.childrenValues, childrenNodes.count > 0 {
                    Section(header: Text(node.displayName)) {
                        ForEach(childrenNodes, id: \.self) { childNode in
                            LibraryNodeChildView(node: childNode).contextMenu {
                                Button(action:{
                                    store.dispatch(LibraryAction.removeNode(childNode))
                                    store.dispatch(LibraryThunkCreatorImpl().persistLibraryState())
                                }){
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Delete")
                                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    }
                                }
                                Button(action:{
                                    
                                }){
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Edit Preferences")
                                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .onAppear() {
            store.dispatch(LibraryThunkCreatorImpl().loadLibraryState())
        }.onDrop(of: ["public.url","public.file-url"], isTargeted: nil) { (items) -> Bool in
            if let item = items.first {
                if let identifier = item.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first {
                    print("onDrop with identifier = \(identifier)")
                    if identifier == "public.url" || identifier == "public.file-url" {
                        item.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: identifier, options: nil) { (urlData, error) in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                if let urlData = urlData as? Data {
                                    let url = NSURL(absoluteURLWithDataRepresentation: urlData, relativeTo: nil) as URL
                                    let thunk = LibraryThunkCreatorImpl().createAddNodeThunk(url: url)
                                    store.dispatch(thunk)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true
            } else {
                print("item not here")
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LibraryNodeChildView: View {
    let node: LibraryNode
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let image = node.image {
                Image(nsImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            }
            Text(verbatim: node.displayName).onDrag {
                NSItemProvider(object: node.url as NSURL)                
            }.allowsHitTesting(false)
            .font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/l5r8au/has_anyone_successfully_used_the_contextmenu_with/) the solution would be to bind the drag and drop to the item container and bind the context menu to the item within the container.

```
HStack {
   Text(verbatim: node.displayName)
       .contextMenu {
           // handle context menu
       }
   }
   .onDrag {
       // handle drag
   }
}
```